# Display Jquery Response in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning PHP and JavaScript. I have form using DropZone.js which upload files and giving response using Jquery Like below

```
<form class="dropzone" id = "image-upload" method="POST" action="upload.php">
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="brand" class="form-control" placeholder="Brand Name" required autofocus>
                <label for="brand"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="reference" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference" required>
                <label for="reference"></label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-label-group">
            
            <input name="attached_files" value=""  />

            </div>
                           
            </form>
```

and JavaScript Like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        jQuery(".dropzone").dropzone({
            
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            success : function(file, response) {
                //console.log(file);
                console.log(response);
                if (response['target_file'] != '') {
                    var currentValue = jQuery("#image-upload input[name='attached_files'").val();
                    if (currentValue == '') {
                        jQuery("#image-upload input[name='attached_files'").val(response['target_file']);
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#image-upload input[name='attached_files'").val(currentValue + ", " + response['target_file']);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Its working fine as expected and showing me uploaded files in

```
 <input name="attached_files" value=""  />
```

But instead I want it as `comma separated and <pre></pre>` so it can look more better. Let me know if someone can help me for achieving my goal.

Thanks!

Comment: An `<input>` is not a `<pre>`, although you can style it to look similar. Is that what you want? Exactly how is it displaying now?